# "firmly insist on your opinion" or "insist on your opinion firmly"?

Tags: word-usage, adverb-placement

Please could you help me to understand how's right way:

> You have to insist on your opinion **firmly**.
> You have to **firmly** insist on your opinion.

Comment: OR *You have to insist **firmly** on your opinion*. Adverbs (such as ***firmly***, here) are often quite flexible as regards position. They can usually go immediately before or after the relevant verb (***insist***, here), or at the end of the entire utterance (sometimes described as a "whole sentence adverb"). It's really a stylistic choice that doesn't necessarily make any difference to the meaning (adverb position certainly doesn't affect meaning with *this* example). But on ppurely stylistic grounds, I'd go for the whole sentence format here (your first version).

Comment: Note that it's not very idiomatic to put the adverb at the *front* of the utterance in this specific case, but that's a perfectly acceptable alternative position for a whole sentence adverb in very closely related contexts, such as ***Doggedly**, he insisted on his opinion*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is correct: the master’s dissertation will <officially> be <officially> added <officially> to your curriculum](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100672/which-is-correct-the-master-s-dissertation-will-officially-be-officially-ad) One of the answers there discusses all the places the adverb can be placed in their example sentence, and I think reading it will help you.

Comment: The second option has a "split infinitive." This has been called a mistake in the past. [Most people agree today that it should be allowed](https://www.theguardian.com/science/shortcuts/2017/sep/25/to-boldly-go-split-infinitive-grammatical-error-research), but you might want to avoid it in case your readers disagree.